# Is there a version of Android Emulator that doesn't need JDK installed?

Tags: android-emulator

I would like to run something through an Android emulator.  Does anyone know if there is a version that doesn't require the JDK to be installed?

I have JRE, but I am not able to install JDK due to current configuration of another piece of software on this machine.  (If I pretend there was an error finding JDK and install anyways, the program seems to fire up for about 3 seconds and then just kills itself)

Comment: You could run on a physical device instead.

Comment: Or you could run the emulator in a virtual machine, such as http://blogs.nuxeo.com/dev/2011/10/speeding-up-the-android-emulator.html

Comment: I want to cut down on how many times I borrow devices from people.  Good idea... thanks Greg!  If you throw that in as an answer, I'll accept it as the right one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to avoid your installation issue is to run the Android device in a virtual machine. For example, [How to speed up the Android Emulator by up to 400%](http://blogs.nuxeo.com/dev/2011/10/speeding-up-the-android-emulator.html) describes how to do this. As a bonus, it can run much faster than the "standard" emulator.